# Unable to connect with remote RabbitMQ server

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, remote-access, masstransit

I'm creating a client application with the idea of publish new messages to a remote RabbitMQ queue. I'm using MassTransit to create this client, and my code looks this way:

```
    static IBusControl CreateBus()
    {
        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
        {             
            var host = x.Host(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQHost"]), h =>
            {
                h.Username("user");
                h.Password("password");
            });

        });
    }

    static IRequestClient<ISyncProject, IProjectSynced> CreateRequestClient(IBusControl busControl)
    {
        var serviceAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceAddress"]);
        IRequestClient<ISyncProject, IProjectSynced> client =
            busControl.CreateRequestClient<ISyncProject, IProjectSynced>(serviceAddress, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

        return client;
    }

    private static async Task MainLogic(IBusControl busControl)
    {
        IRequestClient<ISyncProject, IProjectSynced> client = CreateRequestClient(busControl);

       //I'm using the client here as I show below, this part is not important it works with localhost
        IProjectSynced response = await client.Request(new ProjecToSync() { OriginalOOMID = OriginalOOMID });
    }
```

And the config file looks like this:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="RabbitMQHost" value="rabbitmq://ServerName" />
<add key="ServiceQueueName" value="queueName" />
<add key="ServiceAddress" value="rabbitmq://ServerName/queueName" />
</appSettings>
```

I'm not using guest user, I created a new one and I added all the rights as administrator.
[image]

Now this code works if I run the client application in the same server where is running RabbitMQ and also changing `ServerName` by `localhost`. If I run the client in my local machine using whatever ServerName or IP address of server, RabbitMQ is blocking my connection:

[image]

I presume this is has to be with some configuration that I need to do in the server but I have not found it so far.

One thing I noticed now is disk space is in red and and a big amount of generic exchanges have been created
[image]

Comment: You're missing some much-needed detail. What error are you getting? Is this machine on the same subnet or a different subnet? Is there a firewall or other pass-through device that could be in the way?

Comment: Yes same subnet

Comment: OK, I just saw the last image. So, if that issue where it says "blocking" is the problem, then everything else in this post is irrelevant. There is a [page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/connection-blocked.html) that describes conditions - have you looked there?

Comment: Yes I saw it, but that is to be notified if the connection was blocked or not, right? Probably is the firewall of server

Comment: No, blocking is something the server does when you have a resource issue. You have not provided any details as to what is going on with the server, so I am not able to even speculate. Memory or disk space, perhaps?

Comment: Well, I see Disk space in red,I'm going to add an image. One thing I noticed now is a big amount of exchanges have been created

Comment: I can’t explain the proliferation of exchanges, but I can explain your server not accepting messages due to lack of sufficient space

Comment: @theMayer, thanks for all the help, I will take a look why is creating those generic exchanges. The thing I don't understand is why using localhost and running the client application in the server it can connect with server even without disk space

Comment: This is just how it is designed. It looks like you have a generic server configuration/hardware problem though, and not something programming-related. Not knowing what else could be in play, this is a problem you'll have to work through on your own to see if you can figure it out.

Comment: Yes, it was the space, thanks so much sir ;). If you post an answer I will accepted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question shows, down at the bottom you have a connection, but it is blocked.

[The RabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/alarms.html) lists some conditions where a connection is blocked. These generally have to do with resource limitations on the broker machine itself.  In this case, we've managed to get a clear picture that the free disk space available to the broker is below its low-water mark. Thus, all connections will be blocked until this condition is resolved (either lower the mark - not recommended, or increase the available free space).